# ajax pass a list of int to asp net api controller, parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to pass a list of int ids into my controller, but when the data hits the controller action, the parameter is null

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetReport(int[] items)
    {
        var viewModel = await _reportLogic.GetReportByIdAsync(items);
       // return something;
    }
```

I have this code in my front end

```
        $('#testPreviewList').click(function (e) {
        var items = new Array();
        $('.reportId').each(function () {
            items.push(this.id);
        });
        console.log(items);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/home/GetReport",
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { "items": items},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
                });
                $("#datos").html(row);
                $('#authorNameTextBox').val('');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: Use [FromBody] in public async Task<ActionResult> GetReport([FromBody] int[] items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use POST instead of GET.
Use Traditional property in ajax, set to true.

`$.ajax({
            url: "/home/GetReport",
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { "items": items},
            dataType: "json",
            Traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
                });
                $("#datos").html(row);
                $('#authorNameTextBox').val('');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //alert("Error");
            }
        });`